# Simple keybind preview in textbox

Tags: c#

I want to use a textbox to show the current keybind, and also register the hotkey

I use this atm

```
RegisterHotKey(this.Handle, id, (int)startmo, Enum.Parse(typeof(Keys), startkeyvalue).GetHashCode());
```

To register the hotkey in the textbox in

But, i would like an easy script to show the current keypress in a textbox

for example

Textbox text: CTRL + SHIFT + R

Like this

http://prntscr.com/9e1cqn

Comment: What have you tried ? (hint hint : https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.windows.forms.control.keypress(v=vs.110).aspx)

Comment: I would suggest using the Keydown event, where you can check which Keys are being pressed.

Comment: @Pogrindis thats more for typing with numbers in a textbox i assume?

Comment: @joko i do got somthing like that with the kedown event but i use like 30 lines for that, wich i tink could be way easyer

Comment: Been a while since i used key down but i think you can capture it pretty easily, maybe take a look at the documentation

Comment: @joko yeah i know how to do it but i want the "easy" method